# Can't run my test JUnit step definition

Tags: testing, junit, cucumber, runner

I want to run test JUnit  i work in 2 different projets :

In the first one i have
The feature :

```
Feature: Google Search

Scenario: Validate google search text field
Given open a browser
When navigate to google page
Then validate search text field
```

The Step definition Class :

```
@Given("^open a browser$")
    public void open_a_browser() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Drive\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @When("^navigate to google page$")
    public void navigate_to_google_page() throws Throwable {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }

    @Then("^validate search text field$")
    public void validate_search_text_field() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium "); }
```

And the Runner class :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features={"src\\test\\resources\\com\\tutoriel\\testing\\features\\Googlesearch.feature",
glue={"com\\tutoriel\\testing\\stepdefinitions"})
public class RunTestRunner {
}
```

And it works for me very good

but when i tr to add those 3steps  (feature, stepdef and the runner ) in an big another project it doesn't work 
i don't undersand the issue !!

this is the error

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
```

but i have already defined them in the class steps definition 
Anyone can help me please

Comment: Check the path of the glue code in the bigger project... Are you placing the java step def files correctly

Comment: i changed the path but is the step definition and the runner in the same package ?

Comment: You can place the classes anywhere as long as it is in the classpath. Can you add how the classes are kept in the packages.

Comment: in src/test/resources in have the feature in package and in src/test/java i have 2 others packages  one for the runner and another for stepdefinition but now i have this error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.soprahr.foryou.automation.steps.StepDefinition

Comment: So this:  line glue={"com\\tutoriel\\testing\\stepdefinitions"}  should point to where you keep your stepdefinitions. so it probalbly has something along the lines of  test/something/stepdefinitions ...

Comment: can u add the expanded image of the folder structure with the relevant files? Also the runner updated cucumber options..

Comment: i update it can u see it  !!! i'm very thankful for your help

Comment: @user6618310 There is an issue with your classpath. That is why the runner is not being found